# Questions about neural networks ability

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Is it possible to increase the number of hidden layers and decrease the number of connections without losing the learning ability? More clearly, do a 3 hidden-layer network with 2 connections between each adjacent layer and 2 hidden-layer network with 3 connections between each adjacent layer have the same or similar ability? THX.

Comment: Learning ability for what problem? Yes simple network may work for simple problems, but more completed ones may need more complicated network...

Comment: Maybe I didn't say it clearly. Let me ask in another way:  is it true that one can achieve the same performance with a fully connected networks and a partial connected networks but having more hidden layers?
I only wonder how the learning ability "function" relates to the number of layers and connections. You may assume the problem is pattern recognitions or otherwise. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't have the same ability.

The fact that the middle layer has only 2 nodes in one and 3 in your other case is fundamental to the capacity of the network. It's similar than just simple principal components analysis. 2 components will to be able to describe as much of the variability of an ensemble than 3 components.

Mathematically, the cardinal of real values is not the cardinal of complex values and you have the same problem with the size of 2 real numbers with 3 numbers. You cannot describe triplets of real numbers with duplets.

This reduction is also the basis of autoencoders, if such an equivalence were true, then we would not be able to talk about dimensionality of the embedded space.

Comment: Thanks for your huge response. 
So you mean that the function of layer is totally different from the function of connections?
In fact, I wonder to replace fully connected networks with neighborhood connected networks maybe having more layers but the same or similar ability so that I can implement it by VLSI. But it seems not quite easy (or impossible)......

Comment: In lots of ways, yes. I understand this as the dense layers will try to approximate a function, the more layers, the more non linearities and the nodes give potential options for layers to build these non linearities.

Comment: The idea is always to exploit knowledge and inject it inside the network design (CNN are just that, simplifying dense untrainable layers with knowledge about what image processing is)

Comment: I see. I have surveyed many related refences but few of them mention the principle how or why NN can learn in detail. Your asnwer is helpful. I'll digest your word gradually:)

Comment: It's a black box, you cannot know what part of the network is doing what, expect specialized layers (like CNN which give the preprocessing filters). Still a research process. BUT you can understand what is going on and what you need to describe a function even if you don't know the details.

Comment: You don't how it works but it just can work.  That is not friendly for a beginner... Could you suggest some materials or topis that might help me in my research? THX

Comment: I think the best way is to try on toy examples. For instance try an autoencoder on the swissroll. I think it gets very clear how a network can approximate such a complex function (rcos r, rsin r)

Comment: The result is amazing. NN sucessfully selects the vital features of rolls. 

Now I know NN can learn but still can't explain it... Do we have to do lots of tries and errors to find the best model maybe with some empirical sense？ And if we don't understand what is inside the black box, how can we know or persuade us that the black box will work before running simulation?

Comment: What you can do is analyse the weight in your layers to see how they fit together.

Comment: I understand these weights can span the output images. But why NN can get these weights by just connecting with each others and doing some calculation even we don't know the exact detail. It's quite nontrivial.

Comment: It's optimizing a cost function and random starting noise. This creates specialized nodes that will tackle the beginning of the cost function or the values for biffer `r`. The magic is just back propagation, which is a common algorithm for several decades now.

Comment: I know the standard step to do machine learnring. But don't know how to select an optimal model(topology, algorithm, parameters, cost function...etc) because it's a black box so that I can't analyze it before doing it. That is why I asked the first question about the ability beacuse I think I can predict the result if I know what is NN doing in detail.

Comment: Basically the first layers are always feature extraction, so convolution layers for images or audio, then you had RNN if you have some Markov dependency that you need to model. These are the basic rules that you want to master.

Comment: I know some standard methods but how to choose the best model before simulation? 

I mean that, for example, in filter design, We can calculate the order and the cutoff frequency of an optimal Butterworth filter and we can predict the result before simulation. 
Can we analyze a certain model in ML so that we can decide the optimal number of each parameters and also predict the results before simulation? What do we know about the performance before simulation? Is there some equations of the results maybe with parameters? Sorry for lots of fundamental questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible for neural networks, it's heavily dependent on the data you have. This is still a research domain :(

Comment: Okay I see... I learn a lot from your respose. Thanks for your help. I think I know NN much better than before :)